# What is the error in DELETE query when using joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

Code is running fine when commenting DELETE statement and trying with SELECT statement.
Please help

```
DELETE FROM 
--select * from 
Site as s
join 
(select SiteID,Code, Name, Dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by SiteID ) as Rank from Site
) as t 
on s.SiteID = t.SiteID
WHERE t.Rank != 1
```

Getting following error message

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: Sql Server, But i think this problem is generic to Sql query

Comment: No it's not generic as not all DBMS support a JOIN in a delete statement and some have a completly different syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't alias a `delete` table, but `delete` can refer to an alias.  Instead of this:

```
delete from Site as s
...
```

Try:

```
delete from s
from Site as s
...
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation `You can't alias a delete table, but delete can refer to an alias` I am working on Sql for more than 2-3 years and every time I had to look for this syntax but didn't know the reason. Probably I won't ask same question again. Thanks